# Printing all items of list on its own line

Tags: list, recursion, erlang

I'm having trouble understanding why my function seems to loop endlessly in my recursion:

```
-module(list_tut).
-export([print_cities/1]).
-author("kimput").

print_cities([]) ->
  ok;

print_cities([H|T]) ->
  io:format('city: ~p~n', [H]),
  [H|print_cities([T])].
```

If I enter a list of cities like:

`> list_tut:print_cities(['Moscow', 'Tokyo', 'Stockholm']).`

It prints all the items rather quickly and then keeps printing `cities: []`.

I understand this is an absolute beginner's question, but I've been looking at this problem for a long time now and can't figure out a way of solving it without adding tail-recursion or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're recursing with `[T]` instead of `T`. `T` is the tail of the list which is already a list (if the list is not an improper list). Your code is wrapping the tail in another list, which means in addition to an infinite recursion, the initial elements printed are also wrong:

```
1> c(list_tut).
{ok,list_tut}
2> list_tut:print_cities(['Moscow', 'Tokyo', 'Stockholm']).
city: 'Moscow'
city: ['Tokyo','Stockholm']
city: []
city: []
city: []
city: []
city: []
...
```

Changing `[H|print_cities([T])].` to `[H|print_cities(T)].` fixes this:

```
-module(list_tut).
-export([print_cities/1]).
-author("kimput").

print_cities([]) ->
  ok;

print_cities([H|T]) ->
  io:format('city: ~p~n', [H]),
  [H|print_cities(T)].
```

```
1> c(list_tut).
{ok,list_tut}
2> list_tut:print_cities(['Moscow', 'Tokyo', 'Stockholm']).
city: 'Moscow'
city: 'Tokyo'
city: 'Stockholm'
['Moscow','Tokyo','Stockholm'|ok]
```

---

I'm not sure why you're recreating the list in a print function, but if you want the original list back, the `[]` case should return `[]` if you want the final return value to be the same as the initial one.

```
...
print_cities([]) ->
  [];
...
```

```
1> c(list_tut).
{ok,list_tut}
2> list_tut:print_cities(['Moscow', 'Tokyo', 'Stockholm']).
city: 'Moscow'
city: 'Tokyo'
city: 'Stockholm'
['Moscow','Tokyo','Stockholm']
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was certain it was a small mistake somewhere in the code. God, I feel ashamed now.. :P